# Cycles in LineString in PostGIS table?

Tags: postgis, openlayers

I have a LineString table in PostGIS, which represents wiring in streets. Where the geometry column represents the wiring lines; firstpoint is the first geometry point (cable segment); lastpoint the last geometry point; id_startpoint and id_enpoint are identifiers of the firstpoint and lastpoint columns.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

In OpenLayers v5 it is shown as follows:

[image: Tabla Line en PostGIS]

The point is that I want to detect the rings (cycles) in the structure of the network. As shown below:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

My solution was to use the DFS algorithm in javascript to detect cycles in undirected graphs, which works well until I give the 5327 registers (too much data), however with 200 registers it works fine. For this reason, I want to use some PostGIS function to find the cycles. You could recommend some function to me since there is ST_NumInteriorRings and ST_ExteriorRing but they are for polygons, I need a function for LineString.

Comment: Have you tried using the Topology extension, for example: https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ValidateTopology.html